# Infinite limit of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, limits-without-lhopital, laurent-series

Question
$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^2 + i x} $$

The related info (following solution and plot taken from Wolfram Alpha)
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{1}{x^2 + i x} = i \infty
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1}{x^2 + i x} = (-i) \infty
$$
[image: plot]

Why is the real part being ignored here when in plot it can be clearly seen that the real part is converging to 1 and imaginary part is diverging?

In my opinion the limit should be either $1-(\infty)i$  or  $1+(\infty)i$ depending on the side from which we approach.
If not can you clear my doubt how can we neglect the real part present here?

Answer (score 2):

Your opinion seems correct in one sense. I think the reason for the ambiguity is that in complex analysis, people usually only talk about one complex infinity (denoted just $\infty$ or $\hat\infty$). Here is the reasoning: multiplying your expression by the complex conjugate of the denominator, we get
$$\frac1{x^2+ix}=\frac{x^2-ix}{x^4+x^2}=\frac1{x^2+1}-\frac i{x^3+x}.$$
From here one easily computes the limits of the real and imaginary parts. It is certainly correct to say the real part approaches $1$ and the imaginary part approaches $\mp\infty$ as $x\to0^{\pm}$.

However less common is another notion called [directed infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_infinity) which asks in which direction in the complex plane the convergence occurs. This would be something in the form $z\infty$, meaning infinity in the direction of $\arg(z)$. This must be what Wolfram Alpha is telling you, since asymptotically $1\pm i\infty$ is parallel to the ray starting at $0$ passing through $\pm i$.

Comment: Thank you, What confused me was that I tried the 3d plot of the function and found out that if u imagine yourself to stand at the origin, you can clearly see the value of real to be 1,but the imaginary part to be far far away(aka infinity) .Now visualising the function standing at that point just told me not to ignore the finite real part as it's location was different from zero and was clearly visible. This helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The explanation of Funktorality is correct. If u consider the function it is a function from Reals to Complex. Now if u see the definition of limit is that as $x$ tends to $0$ $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$ that mod is norm on the complex plane if such $l$ exist then it has a limit $l$. But certainly $l$ must belongs to complex. Now if u break the norm then real part and imaginary part must converge together to exist the limit.